# CSS line height problem - Can't get an exact number of lines

Tags: html, css, fonts

I found a much older post on this subject, but for a lot of people the most popular answer nor any of the other answers worked. Many years later, that includes me.

I'm trying to make a `div` exactly 19 lines tall (ultimately I'm heading for 19.5 lines, so you'll always see exactly half a line when there's more text to scroll to, but I'm trying for 19 first.) As I resize my browser window, however, I see various fractional excesses of text: exactly the issue I'm trying to prevent. Below, around 19 and roughly a half lines are showing:

[image: screenshot]

Here's the CSS that I'm using, for both the outer `div` shown above, and the inner darker `div`:

```css
#marquee-dialog > div {
  font-size: 3vh;
  line-height: 3.6vh;
  position: absolute;
  margin: auto;
  top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0;
  width: 80vw;
  height: 80vh;
  padding: 1em;
  background-color: white; /* Changed via JavaScript later */
  color: black;
}

#marquee-big-text {
  font-size: 3vh;
  line-height: 3.6vh;
  max-height: 22.8em;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

I've set my line height to 1.2 times larger than the font size, and my `max-height` to 19 * 1.2 = 22.8 em. (I've also tried 68.4vh instead, and setting `height` along with, or instead of `max-height`, and it made no difference.) That certainly seems like it should come out to 19 lines, as exactly as floating point precision allows.

When I check the web console, the height of the `div` comes out exactly, or almost exactly, 19 times the line height, and almost exactly 22.8 times the `em` size, which I can check by checking the size of the padding of the outer `div`.

The inner `div` has 0 padding, 0 margin, and 0 border to throw the numbers off.

From all of the numeric values I'm seeing, I'm getting my 19 lines. But the rendering is nevertheless rendering just a bit more. The excess appears in Chrome, Firefox, and Safari.

I must be missing something obvious?

**UPDATE**

I tried this, with exact pixel values taken from the web console:

```css
#marquee-big-text {
  font-size: 3vh;
  line-height: 31.968px; /* 3.6vh; */
  max-height: 607.392px; /* 22.8em; */
  overflow: auto;
}
```

I still get the same problem, even though these are close-to-exact values for 19 lines.

**UPDATE 2**

I took some measurements off my screenshot. Based on measuring from baseline to baseline, each text line *as rendered* is 62 pixels tall. The entire `div` is 1212 pixels tall. With those measurements about 19.55 lines should fit in that space, explaining what I'm seeing. For there to be something closer to exactly 19 lines, the baseline-to-baseline measurement should be about 63.79 pixels, almost 2 pixels more per line.

This seems almost like rendering round-off error, but it's curious, if it's round-off, that the round-off would be consistent from browser to browser.

**UPDATE 3**

Here's a working example:

https://codepen.io/kshetline/pen/NWNGOWL

Interestingly, with this simplified example, the problem still shows up with Chrome and Safari, but somehow Firefox always gets it right.

You may have to switch the Codepen view to this orientation:

[image: codepen screenshot]

...to see the problem. The bug only kicks in at fairly large font sizes, and as I resize the browser window the excess never gets much beyond half a line before snapping back to 19 lines.

More and more this looks like a font-size round off error. I'm guessing it's related to rendering optimization, avoiding the caching of big font bitmaps of too many small differences in font size.

Comment: Have you tried using the `ch` unit? Seems like that's exactly what you need. Give it a try.

Comment: Since `ch` is relative to the *width* of the 0 character I'm not sure how I would use that to relate to my line *height*.

Comment: That indeed might be the case; I was speculating that it might work on the height attribute, not line-height. Sorry if that did not help.

Comment: Please add a [mcve] to your question.

Comment: I'd think that the CSS tells the story, but OK.

Comment: You could do `height: calc(calc(3vh * 19) + 1.5vh)`

Where 3vh is your line-height and 1.5vh is your offset.

Comment: @Rod911, it's not always off by half a line, however. The error varies as you resize your browser window. Sometimes it's correctly 19 lines, other times there's some variable fraction of a line added on.

Comment: @kshetline https://codepen.io/rod911/pen/bGpEbgm something along these lines?

Comment: Thanks, @Rod911. I tried your Codepen, and I still see variable amounts of a partial line showing at the bottom of the div as I resize the browser window when I use Chrome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not the kind of answer I was hoping for, but I can fix the problem with JavaScript. It seems that I have to force the use of integer pixel sizes to make exact line counts occur dependably.

```js
const middiv = document.querySelector('.outer > div');
const inner = document.querySelector('.inner');
let lastLineHeight = 0;

function checkFont() {
  const style = document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(middiv, null);
  const exactHeight = parseFloat(style.getPropertyValue('line-height'));
  const roundedHeight = Math.floor(exactHeight);

  if (lastLineHeight !== roundedHeight) {
    inner.style.lineHeight = roundedHeight + 'px';
    inner.style.maxHeight = (roundedHeight * 19) + 'px';
    lastLineHeight = roundedHeight;
  }
}

window.addEventListener('resize', checkFont);
checkFont();
```

Here's a Codepen to demo this: https://codepen.io/kshetline/pen/vYGLjBo